# Java Server SSL Socket and Python Client SSL socket - problems when server send messages

Tags: java, python, ssl, client

I'm trying communicate a server SSL socket Java and a client SSL socket Python. The first message sent is ok, but when the server sends another messages, the client receives the messages dividing in 2 parts. For example: If the server send message "abcdefghij", the client receives first "a", and after "bcdefghij".

Somebody knows why after the first time the messages are received in two parts? Regards.

The client code:

```
import socket, ssl, pprint
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
ssl_sock.connect(('localhost', 7000))
pprint.pprint(ssl_sock.getpeercert())

while(1):
    print "Waiting"
    data = ssl_sock.recv()  
    print "Received:", data
    data = ""

ssl_sock.close()
```

The server code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;


public class SslReverseEchoer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char ksPass[] = "123456".toCharArray();
        char ctPass[] = "123456".toCharArray();

        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("keystore.jks"), ksPass);
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, ctPass);
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
            SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
            SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(7000);
            printServerSocketInfo(s);
            SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
            printSocketInfo(c);
            BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            //1th time
            String m = "abcdefghj1234567890";
            w.write(m, 0, m.length());
            w.newLine();
            w.flush();
            //2th time
            String m2 = "#abcdefghj1234567890";
            w.write(m2, 0, m2.length());
            w.newLine();
            w.flush();
            //3th time
            String m3 = "?abcdefghj1234567890";
            w.write(m3, 0, m3.length());
            w.newLine();
            w.flush();
            while ((m = r.readLine()) != null) {
                if (m.equals("."))
                    break;
                char[] a = m.toCharArray();
                int n = a.length;
                for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                    char t = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[n - 1 - i];
                    a[n - i - 1] = t;
                }
                w.write(a, 0, n);
                w.newLine();
                w.flush();
            }
            w.close();
            r.close();
            c.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    private static void printSocketInfo(SSLSocket s) {
        System.out.println("Socket class: " + s.getClass());
        System.out.println("   Remote address = " + s.getInetAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Remote port = " + s.getPort());
        System.out.println("   Local socket address = " + s.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Local address = " + s.getLocalAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Local port = " + s.getLocalPort());
        System.out.println("   Need client authentication = " + s.getNeedClientAuth());
        SSLSession ss = s.getSession();
        System.out.println("   Cipher suite = " + ss.getCipherSuite());
        System.out.println("   Protocol = " + ss.getProtocol());
    }

    private static void printServerSocketInfo(SSLServerSocket s) {
        System.out.println("Server socket class: " + s.getClass());
        System.out.println("   Socker address = " + s.getInetAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Socker port = " + s.getLocalPort());
        System.out.println("   Need client authentication = " + s.getNeedClientAuth());
        System.out.println("   Want client authentication = " + s.getWantClientAuth());
        System.out.println("   Use client mode = " + s.getUseClientMode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you expect to be always able to read whatever quantity of data you've sent in one block from the other side.

This is a common mistake, not specific to SSL/TLS, but also related to plain TCP communications.

You should always loop and read whatever you intend to read. You should also define your protocol (or use an existing one) to take into account commands and request/response terminators.

HTTP, for example, uses blank lines to tell the end of the headers and the `Content-Length` header or chunked transfer encoding to tell the recipient when to stop reading the body.

SMTP uses line-delimited commands and a single `.` for the end of a message.

Comment: This is all true on a general sense but it's the naggle/ack interaction that causes the specific behavior he's seeing. It also causes a ~ 40ms delay between the two packets which is a serious problem if one of your requirements is performance. Ever see two people standing 10 feet away from each other, each waiting for the other person to arrive? It's that. Really annoying little bugger to track down until you watch it in a packet sniffer. (If you're never sending small chunks of data, you don't see it).

Comment: @BrianRoach, your answer explains this particular point, but people shouldn't rely on this in general (you can't always know whether the remote party is using the Naggle algo). The OP's expectations go hand in hand with trying to detect connection closures using only reads (another common mistake).

Comment: Fair point. I think a combination of our two answers pretty much covers all the bases. I'm not a python guy at all - is his `recv()` returning whatever is in the TCP buffer at the time of the call but blocks if there's nothing?

Comment: I changed the code from the server and client according to comments from you and yet always after the first transmission of the first byte following messages are sent, and the rest of the message arrives later.
The protocol that assembled to identify the messages will have to be changed thanks for the help.

Comment: But do not think the problem is that since the implementation using Python as client and server, or Java as a client and server did not happen, also tests with C client and server, the problem did not happen. As test with C and Python as client and server did not happen. Only when I use Java and C, or Java and Python is described.

Comment: @DavidViana It can happen any time, Java, Perl, C, C++, Ada, SSL, plaintext. There is nothing in TCP that says it won't happen. Code accordingly.

Comment: @EJP Sorry but tcp is guaranteed to deliver the order. What is happening in the code with Java and other languages ​​as a server as a client, is that for some reason, there is a breakdown of the message, like the finalizer recebece making the function that expects the package to be called twice by the message that transmitted only once. What I do not understand is why this does not happen when I use client and server using the same language.

Comment: @EJP I did tests combining client and server in various ways Java and Java, Python and Python, C and C, C and Python.
Only when tested with Java and Python, Java and C and finally had to break the message.

Comment: @DavidViana, TCP guarantees the order, not the number of times you'll have to try to read. The fact that you get different results depending on the language is a side issue. You're trying to solve the wrong problem (or a problem that isn't one). The fact that you may have to read your input buffer multiple times is normal behaviour, even if this behaviour changes slightly depending on the platform you're using.

Comment: @Bruno Actually the problem should not be platform, however proved to be a problem but the platform, and it always happens after the first transmission of the message, always sending the first character prior to sending the rest of the message later.

Comment: Is there an unacceptable delay between those read attempts, or is it almost instantaneous?

Comment: I haven't used SSL sockets "manually" for a while in Python, but you should consider using `read` instead of `recv`.

Comment: @DavidViana I didn't say anything about TCP not guaranteeing the order. The problem we are discussing is the amount of data being received by individual reads. Please don't put words into my mouth.

Comment: @EJP Please excuse me, I did not say you said, I just wanted to say that I disagreed because as I said in my tests, it seems the problem only happens when you mix Java with other languages. And you generalized telling what can happen at any time, and I disagree. Excuse me once again it seemed that I meant what you said no. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of the Naggle algorithm on the server side and delayed ACK in the client's TCP stack. You'll also find ~ 40ms delay between the two packets.

Disable the Naggle algo on the server side to remedy:

```
SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
c.setTcpNoDelay(true);
```

More information on why this occurs here: http://www.stuartcheshire.org/papers/NagleDelayedAck/

**Edit to add:** Note Bruno's answer below. While this describes the specific reason for what you're seeing here, the way you're expecting data from the server is not guaranteed.

Comment: +1 for explaining the cause here, but this doesn't fix the fundamental problem.

Comment: @BrianRoach I changed the code from the server and client according to comments from you and yet always after the first transmission of the first byte following messages are sent, and the rest of the message arrives later. The protocol that assembled to identify the messages will have to be changed thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve my problem in two ways, the message always break at the first character, so I decided to add three spaces at the beginning of each message and end. So when the client receives them do a trim on the message.
Another way I found was using DataOutputStream, the method that delivers writeBytes byte by byte, used it on the server and the client had q change as it receives data, the message had to build client-side processing to finally do what I want to house the end of message. Thanks for the discussion!

Comment: What you don't seem to understand is that a TCP connection gives you a continuous stream of data. The chunks you write on one end are not necessarily the chunks that you read on the other end. What TCP guarantees is only the order of the overall sequence, when all the chunks are concatenated together. Using spaces as delimiters can work, but you'll always need to concatenate the buffers and keep looping until you read those spaces.

Comment: Sorry I did in the second approach in my solution. However, only a little strange because from what I read the TCP packet is 1460 bytes in size, so for me, was to come across these 1460 bytes exactly as I wrote at one end. And of course my read buffer should have booked this size, if not to get broken. I appreciate the explanation and understand that I must ride to the received message then process it. Thank again.

Comment: The 1460-byte limit is probably due to something related to the MTU. Again, don't worry about it. With TCP, you're meant to keep reading your buffer for however many times it takes to get the message you want, up to the delimiter you've defined. Expecting data to turn up in fragments of the right size is just the wrong approach.